# How to adjust vase mode thickness

Tags: prusa-i3, prusaslicer

I am new to 3D printing, and are having a problem with wall thickness in vase mode.
I would like to print this vase model: https://www.printables.com/model/60696-blossom-vase

As seen in the "Makes & comments" section, people have printed the model with quite thick walls, and I would like this as well, maybe thicker.

I have a Prusa i3 MK3S+ printer, and are using the Prusa Slicer software. When I import the .stl model and select vase mode in print options, I cannot alter the layer height, solid layers etc. options to increase wall thickness. This means that the 3D print is almost paper thin.

So how can I make a print of this model, with thick walls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vase mode implies a single wall, so if you need to have a thicker wall you need to set an extrusion width larger than the nozzle width (you cannot do that unlimited), but usually a 0.4 mm nozzle can print at 0.8 mm width (twice the nozzle diameter), or you could replace the nozzle for a wider nozzle, e.g. a 0.8 mm nozzle (and also print at larger diameter). Note that when using larger nozzles/diameters, the extrusion volume increases, so you need to print slower.

Comment: 0.4 mm nozzle can typically print up to at least 1.0 mm line width, and possibly more with reduced quality. The only real constraint is that quality will degrade once the line width exceeds the **outer flat diameter** of the nozzle tip, since material can expand upward around the nozzle rather than outward. Lost in Tech on YouTube has videos showing his results printing really-wide-line vase mode with standard 0.4 mm nozzles.

Comment: I edited my typo 0.5 -> 0.8. Up to twice the diameter is accepted in term of quality. So placing a 0.6 or 0.8 mm nozzle and print at about 1.2 mm would be as if you have a vase with 3 normal 0.4 mm perimeters.

Comment: I measured several of my nozzles and found the outer diameter of the flat for 0.4 mm nozzles between 1.2 and 2.0 mm, so I think 0.8 mm is still pretty conservative.